# How can I add a trigger variable negation in Animation machine's transition in Unity?

Tags: unity, animation

How can I add a trigger variable negation in Animation machine's transition in Unity?

I have two transitions.

First happens if `jump == false && grounded == true && duck == false && shoot`, second happens if `jump == false && grounded == true && duck == false && run == false`. I want to change the second to the `jump == false && grounded == true && duck == false && run == false && !shoot`, i.e. add the trigger variable negation in the end.

How can I achieve this?

First

[image]

Second

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare another Boolean and store the value of the trigger in that Boolean and then use it in the animator.

Comment: I need the trigger functionality. I want the animation to play once and transition further with the trigger being false.

Comment: How about making the second animation state as your default state and when the shoot trigger is activated it will transition to the first state. By definition the trigger after being activated once would revert back to a false state and your animator would transition back to the default state.